# data structure to store piece-wise function

Tags: database, algorithm, math, data-structures

I want to implement a function that:

```
f(x) = a0   -inf < x < b0
       a1    b0 <= x < b1
       a2    b1 <= x < b2
       ...
       an    bn-1 <= x < bn
       an+1  bn <= x < +inf
```

Rather than the plain if-else implementation.

```
def func(x):
    if x<b0: return a0
    elif x<b1: return a1
    .....
```

Do I have a better data structure to organize this?

Also, how could I write a 'meta-function' that return the optimized 'func(x)' given the two sequences {an},{bn}.

Comment: You could have a tuple defined as `[bi,bj]` where `bi < bj` Build a dictionary of `dict[tuple] = an`, it should be `O(1)` look up as long as dictionary is static and not changed after built once.

Comment: There is an `interval` module for Python; try a browser search.

Comment: @Prune I'm more interested in a mathematical / algorithmic solution rather than googling a package.

Answer (score 2):

If `n` is large, you want to reduce the number of `if` statements. In Python, this could be done by storing your data in a dictionary:

```
fx = {b0: a0, b1: a1, b2: a2, ..., bn: an, math.inf: an+1}
```

For a given value of `x`, do a binary search on the key values of the dictionary. That gives you the appropriate key to use, then use the dictionary itself to get the related value. If your language does not allow `inf` as a key, you could keep the value of `an+1` separate from the dictionary, perhaps keeping both in a 2-tuple.

This reduces the maximum number of tests from `n` to `log2(n)`.

The 'meta-function' is easy in Python, since functions are first-class objects in Python. You do not state a preferred language: Let me know if you need an example of the 'meta-function' in Python.

Comment: In order to do binary search, it's required that the items be sorted. Dictionary keys are not necessarily sorted, so that's probably a step OP needs to take on. Given that, I don't know if a dictionary has a benefit here; one has to keep the b's in a sorted list, may as well keep the a's in a parallel list.

Comment: @RobertDodier Thanks. What if I need to change the pivot points without reconstructing the whole list. If there any 'binary tree' trick I can use?

Comment: @RobertDodier: In Python 3.6 and later, standard Python does sort the keys, in the order they were inserted. In Python 3.7 that is the required standard for all implementations of Python. I took that for granted and should not have--thanks for the note. You are right that two lists, one of them sorted, would also work well and in some ways better, but that would mean putting both lists into an overall container structure, which would be more complex than the dictionary I show.

Answer (score 0):

You *could* just store arrays of the a's and b's.  Then to look up a value, you can do a binary search in the `b` array to find the index of the value to return in the `a` array.

That actually performs pretty well, but I came up with a faster way to do this that I think is pretty cool, when I had to implement the state machine for this lexical analysis package (https://github.com/mtimmerm/dfalex).

The representation of your function would be a binary tree stored sequentially in an array, like we commonly do for heaps: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/array-representation-of-binary-heap/

The root of the tree is in `array[0]`, the left child of any `array[i]` is at `array[2i+1]`, and the right child of `array[i]` is at `array[2i+2]`.  The leaves of the tree are all the `a` (result) values in order, and the internal node between each pair of adjacent `a` values is the `b` (argument) value at which you switch from one to another.

The heap-tree-order in the array ensures that all the `a` values occur contiguously at the end.

The benefit of this representation is that you can use this function to look up the appropriate value, which is simpler and faster than a binary search:

```
def lookup(x, array, num_internal_nodes)
    i=0
    while (i < num_internal_nodes):
        i = i*2 + (1 if x<array[i] else 2)
    return array[i]
```

Apologies if I made a mistake with the python syntax -- it's not a language I know well.

If you need to construct a function that just takes the input value, then you can build the array representation and call a function that makes a closure like this:

```
def makeF(array, num_internal_nodes):
    def f(x):
        return lookup(x, array, num_internal_nodes)
    return f
```

To build the array representation of your function in the first place, just make an array of the appropriate size (`num_internal_nodes*2+1`), and then do a pre-order traversal of the tree, filling in the `a` (leaf) and `b` (internal) values in order.

Comment: I was thinking about something like that too, but it seems to me that there is the same number of comparisons (same as binary search in an array, I mean) to find the interval containing a given input. Perhaps I've overlooked something.

Comment: @RobertDodier exactly the same number of comparisons, but fewer other operations and better cache locality